# Drools high memory consumption (version 7.13.Final)

Tags: drools

Problem: Drools is consuming around 1 GB of memory for 10K rules to serve 1000 requests.

Setup: In drl file we have 10K rules. We are using 100 threads and sending 100 requests per second.

While running the test for 1000 requests, we observe that it is consuming around 1 GB memory in VisualVM tool.

Could you please suggest any recommendation to reduce the memory consumption ?

Does Drools rule engine take this much memory for serving 1000 requests and 10K rules?

Comment: What are the 1000 requests/s doing? Are they inserting new data into existing sessions? Are they creating new sessions? What objects do you have in you sessions?

Comment: 1000 requests are the 1000 facts that we were testing with. We are creating new stateless session for each fact (Its a Transaction object with 6 to 7 fields) because when we use only one session, it doesn't fire rules properly for different facts. Please let me know if you have any suggestions.

Comment: Did we find any solution to this?